# Printing an output string in a while loop in Python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

So my question is: Ive created a **while** with a **if-elif-else** clause in the **while** loop. I prompt the user to enter y or n, case insensitive. But I want the loop to keep looping until they enter either a y,Y,n,N to print out the corresponding string. But when I enter any string or integer it keeps looping like I want but when I enter the y,Y,n,N it still keeps looping and doesnt print the strings I want it too.

```
var = input("Enter Y/N:")


while var != 'y' or var != 'Y' or var != 'n' or var != 'N' :
    if var == 'y' or var == 'Y' :
        print("You said yes")
        break
    elif var == 'n' or var == 'N':
        print("You said no")
        break
    else:
        input("Enter Y/N:")
```

Comment: Move the input into your while loop and define `var = ''` at the top (before the loop)

Comment: Your `if` conditions will always jump to `input(...)`

Comment: Yea Im wondering why they wont evaluate. If I delete the input function then I can get the desired conditions to print. But then it wont loop.

Comment: Because you are checking if input is `yes` or `no` and enter the while body only if they are not, then you are checking whether the input is yes/no which will never be true.

Comment: So I put the var = input("Enter Y/N:") in the else clause and it works. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Based on your post it's seems you want a chance to skip the loop based on user's input. To do that you can use this algorithm:

```
var = input("Enter Y/N:")
if var in ['y', 'Y']:
    print("You said yes")
elif var in ['n', 'N']:
    print("You said no")
else:
    while True :
        var = input("Enter Y/N:")
        if var in ['y', 'Y']:
            print("You said yes")
            break
        elif var in ['n', 'N']:
            print("You said no")
            break
```

Why not write **while** with a condition like `var not in ['y', 'Y', 'n', 'N']`?

```
var = input("Enter Y/N:")
if var in ['y', 'Y']:
    print("You said yes")
elif var in ['n', 'N']:
    print("You said no")
while var not in ['y', 'Y', 'n', 'N']:
    var = input("Enter Y/N:")
    if var in ['y', 'Y']:
        print("You said yes")
    elif var in ['n', 'N']:
        print("You said no")
```

We could switch the **else** statement for something more explicit over the **while** statement this will work too but as you can see our code seems to have more cut-points.
The only problem is that we have increased the cut-point with redundant routines.

In my opinion is better and more readable to implement the **input** inside the loop.

for python 3.x

```
while True :
    var = input("Enter Y/N:")
    if var in ['y', 'Y']:
        print("You said yes")
        break
    elif var in ['n', 'N']:
        print("You said no")
        break
```

for python 2.x

```
while True :
    var = raw_input("Enter Y/N:")
    if var in ['y', 'Y']:
        print("You said yes")
        break
    elif var in ['n', 'N']:
        print("You said no")
        break
```

Now we have a very tiny code doing the same thing.

I notice too that you just want to read the letters {y,n}. The case sensitive is a definition useful for the user only, the cases will produce the same answer. So you could just lower or upper all the inputs to simplify your conditions

for python 3.x

```
while True :
    var = input("Enter Y/N:").lower()
    if var == 'y':
        print("You said yes")
        break
    elif var == 'n':
        print("You said no")
        break
```

for python 2.x

```
while True :
    var = raw_input("Enter Y/N:").lower()
    if var == 'y':
        print("You said yes")
        break
    elif var == 'n':
        print("You said no")
        break
```

Comment: Yep thats another solution too. So I can create a list in a if statement?

Comment: didn't get you mate! can you rephrase?

Comment: My question has been answered cause you obviously created a list and it executes lol. Thanks